# Is this a positive definite kernel?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, harmonic-analysis, integral-kernel

Under which conditions on the function :
\begin{array}{l|rcl}
    K : & \mathbb R^+ & \longrightarrow &  (0, 1)\\
        &t & \longmapsto & K(t) \end{array}

is the symmetric function : 
\begin{array}{l|rcl}
    C : & (\mathbb R^+)^2 & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R\\
        & (t,s) & \longmapsto & C(t, s) =\frac{K(t) +K(s)} {2\Gamma(1-\frac{K(t)+K(s)}{2})} \end{array}
a positive definite Kernel ? .Are there references to help me solve this problem ?

NB: $\Gamma$ is the well known Gamma function.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MO. You can edit your own question even after it is posted, instead of adding comments later on. Also, if you are looking for a reference you may want to use the [reference-request] tag